# How to Get Report on Profits from Social Media Networks in DFP?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, ads, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I would like to see specifically how much I am earning from traffic from a specific social media network.

Our project has profiles at different Social Medias, DFP shows us total amount earned, while I would like to see a breakdown oh how much is earned from this/that social network (e.g. Facebook, Pinterest, Twitter, etc).

I share my updates using specific URL parameters for each network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DFP [key values](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177381?hl=en) to accomplish this

1. Pass some variable in the GET request indicating where the traffic is coming from
2. Parse these values in js and set [custom targeting](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_setTargeting) for DFP
3. After that you'll be able to build DFP reports split by specific key values